# What open source library licenses can I use in closed-source?

Tags: licensing, open-source, third-party-libraries

I like to create a closed-source program and sell it.  I would like to make use of various open source libraries to make it easier to write this program.

So how I will choose the libraries that I could use. Which licenses for libraries could I use? I only will use the library - I will not edit the libraries.

Which licenses allowed me to use it for closed-source program?

Comment: LGPL- ed or BSD- or MIT- libraries would be ok, but your question is a FAQ and there are zillions of answers on the web! However, IANAL

Answer (score 7):

If you want to remain free in which license to choose for your own parts of the application, you can use libraries with any license that doesn't try to extend its scope to the entire program, but is limited to the library in question.

So, the licenses that you must avoid are strong copyleft licenses, such as GPL and AGPL.
If you want to use a library with LGPL license, then you must ensure that your users are given the means to replace that library with a version of their own. The users that do this are assumed to have enough programming knowledge to use a compiler.

Comment: And how about `EPL` is it also considered a permissive license?

Comment: @Bionix1441, the EPL is considered a weakly copyleft license.

Answer (score 0):

Most [permissive licenses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permissive_free_software_licence) would be suitable for your purpose, because a permissive license allows to combine the work with another and release it under any license you want. But keep in mind that some conditions might apply, like giving credit to the original authors. So make sure to read the license properly before considering it for use in your project. The most widely-used software licenses of this kind are the [MIT license](http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT) and the [BSD license family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses).

When you don't intend to modify the library, you can also use libraries licensed under the [LGPL](http://opensource.org/licenses/lgpl-license). This version of the GPL has an exception which allows dynamic linking (but not static linking!) with a program under any other license.